# Access localhost ( running on Mac OS X ) from another machine in the network

Tags: macos, networking, webserver, localhost

I have a REST service running on Mac OS X, which im currently accessing using "**localhost:8888**" and "**10.0.2.2:8888**"

I want to access the same service from another computer which is in the same network.

I disabled the firewall also and I typed

```
 nc -v 192.168.1.3 8888
```

and got the result as

```
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.3 port 8888 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

currently i use localhost (to access using java application) and 10.0.2.2 (to access using android application runs in the simulator) which both runs on the same machine which the server runs too.

I want to put the android application to my phone and give the machine ip addess ( because if i connect to internet via wifi, it'll be in the same local area network) i should be able to access my service runs on my machine.

can some one please tell me what im doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: what is the IP address of the machine running your webserver? (run ifconfig from the command line if you aren't sure).

Comment: its 192.168.1.3

Comment: You'll need to configure your "server" to listen on all IPs. E.g. if Apache is configured to listen to `127.0.0.1:80` then that is all it will respond to (localhost). Your server may have a configruation to change to, say, `0.0.0.0:<port>` or `:<port>` to imply everything. You should also consider looking at any firewall rules.

Answer (score -1):

Type 192.168.1.3:8888/rest/getDetails on other computer. Replace rest and getDetails with your request mappings. You do not even need to fiddle with firewall. I am running a Restful app in Java on Mac and able to access on other networked computers.

Comment: -1 because this answer is just "it works for me".